# Is electron revolving clockwise or anticlockwise around nucleus?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter

Ignore the position i.e whether you are on one or other side of orbit. Does space quantization play any role.

Comment: Hi Mubashir. You have probably learned the Bohr model, which describes the electrons as orbiting the nucleus like planets orbit a star. However this isn't what actually happens. The electrons do not orbit the nucleus - not clockwise and not anticlockwise. See the answers to the question I have linked for what actually happens in an atom.

Comment: John..since space quantization is a quantum mechanical concept not classical and in angular momentum we always consider some rotating electron because we say orientation of orbit is quantized i.e  z component of L . Taking space quantization into consideration we can show that there are equal number of electrons in an atom which move clock and anticlockwise. e.g for l=1  there are 3 possible orientations +1 ,0 and -1 It is actually 0 where the flipping occurs electron changes from clock to anticlock. all + l electrons will be clockwise and all - l will be anti.